# Redirect If Authenticated NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using the following tech

- NodeJS
- ExpressJS
- VueJS
- ngnix

i store the `x-access-token` in the `localstorage`.

When the user visits the site `www.example.com` a `vuejs` component does the following

Verifies if the user is logged in by calling an authentication endpoint
If verified, it redirects to `www.example.com/controlpanel`

Ofcourse the problem is it takes a while for the `vuejs` component to load and therefore the page loads and later is redirected.

Is there a way of handling the above scenario in a cleaner way. Using `ngnix` even?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `beforeRouteEnter` navigation guard

Comment: @VamsiKrishna i am not using `vue-router` at all. I am handling the routing in `expressjs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the component which is rendered on the visit to homepage(root route `/`)
add a `beforeRouteEnter()` navigation guard as follows:

```
//in root route component options

beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
    myAjax.get('/auth').then((res) => {
        if(res.data.user){
            //user logged in
            next('/controlpanel');
        }else{
            next('/');
        }
    });
}
```

this guard is called before the route component is rendered and only gets confirmed and rendered if you invoke `next()`

keep in mind you will not have access to the compnents's vue instance as the component is not created yet

to get acceess to t vue instance inside `beforeRouteEnter()` do this:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next){
    next(vm => {
        //acess the component's instance using vm
    }
}
```

For more info check out [In-Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html)

Comment: But i am not using `vue-router`

Comment: Yeah! It does work, but there is still a lag in there. Do you know of a solution that does not involve `vue`?

Comment: @user3052526 there will be lag as you are performing an async operation.... the better solution would be showing a loader

Comment: I think i will implement this solution for now. If anything comes to your mind that does not involve vuejs please share. Thanks man!

Comment: @user3052526 yup will do..... if you find a better solution please feel free to add an edit to my answer:)